# Is the function $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Is the function $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ differentiable at $x=0$?

Would the expression below denote its derivative?

$$  \lim_{x \to 0}  \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{ (1+x+h)^{\frac{1}{x+h}} - e}{h}$$

Comment: What is the letter e?

Comment: Euler's number e

Comment: $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{(1+x+h)^{\frac{1}{x+h}}-e}{h}$ doesn't exist

Comment: Is $(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ defined at $x=0$?

Comment: It's not, so that does mean no derivative?

Comment: If a function is not defined at a point the how can it have derivative? Maybe you miss some extra info like $f(0)=$ something

Comment: nope this was a problem that my friend came up with it. There is no existing conditions

Comment: But it does not makes sence to ask for the derivate at a point for which the function is not defined

Comment: I did not know that the existence of a function at a point is necessary for having derivative. I know the geometric picture looks weird when it's not defined but yeah I wanted to double check

Comment: X=0 is not in the domain of the function. Now one should find out if the limit exists (hole in the graph). If so, then one can set up a piece wise function and then apply the limit definition of the derivative to see if that yields an answer. As it turns out, the hole is at (0,1) and through a piece wise function one can find this to be differentiable. (=-1)

Comment: @imranfat The function has a removable discontinuity at $0$ and, once removed, is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @mark. Yes it is, but I am not so sure if this is clear to the OP, i.e., removable disc. and then differentiable.

Comment: I made a guestimation that the derivative 's value would be -1 by looking at the graph. That's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The function $ (1+x)^{1/x}$ has a ***removable discontinuity*** at $0$, which once removed, renders $(1+x)^{1/x}$ differentiable.

---

We begin by defining a function $f(x)$ such that 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}(1+x)^{1/x}&,x\ne0\\\\e&,x=0\end{cases}$$

---

If the derivative, $f'(0)$, of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ exists, then it is given by the limit $$ f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1+h)^{1/h}-e}{h}$$

---

Proceeding to evaluate the limit, we find that

$$\begin{align}
f'(0)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1+h)^{1/h}-e}{h}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{\frac1h\log(1+h)}-e}{h}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{1-\frac12h+O(h^2)}-e}{h}\\\\
&=e\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-\frac12h+O(h^2)}-1}{h}\\\\
&=e\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-\frac12h+O(h^2)}{h}\\\\
&=-\frac e2
\end{align}$$

Hence, the derivative of $\displaystyle f(x)$ at $\displaystyle 0$ does exist with

$$f'(0)= -\frac e2$$

---

Note that for $x\ne 0$, the derivative, $f'(x)$ of $f(x)$ is given by

$$ f'(x)=\frac{(1+x)^{1/x-1}(x-(1+x)\log(1+x))}{x^2}$$

It is straightforward to show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=-\frac e2$, which shows that $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$.  Hence, $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function 
$$f(x):=(1+x)^{1/x}$$
is undefined for $x\leq-1$ and $x=0$. When we look at
$$g(x):=\log f(x)={1\over x}\log(1+x)={1\over x}\bigl(x-{x^2\over2}+{x^3\over3}-\ldots\bigr)=1-{x\over2}+{x^2\over3}-\ldots$$
then we see that this $g$ is an analytic function when $|x|<1$. In particular $g(0)=1$, which says that we should define $f(0)=e$ and then have
$$f(x)=\exp\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=e\left(1-{x\over2}+{11x^2\over24}-{7x^3\over16}+{2447x^4\over5760}-\ldots\right)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here we have multiplied
$$\exp\bigl(g(x)\bigr)=e^1\cdot e^{-x/2}\cdot e^{x^2/3}\cdot\ldots=e\cdot(1-{x\over2}+\ldots)(1+{x^2\over3}+\ldots)\cdot\ldots$$
and kept all terms of degree $\leq4$. If it is important one could also derive a recursion for the successive coefficients.

In any case, $(1)$ shows that the given $f$, supplemented with $f(0):=e$, is even a real analytic function for $|x|<1$.